# Javascript Next and Previous images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Code is supposed to show next image when clicking on next arrow and previous image when clicked on previous arrow. It does not work though. (error occurs while assigning img.src=imgs[this.i]; it says  Cannot set property 'src' of null
    at collection.next) .

Javascript code :

```js
var arr = new collection(['cake.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png', 'image1.png']);

function collection(imgs) {
  this.imgs = imgs;
  this.i = 0;
  this.next = function(element) {
    var img = document.getElementById('element')
    this.i++;
    if (this.i == imgs.length) {
      this.i = 0;
    }
    img.src = imgs[this.i].src;


  }
  this.prev = function(element) {
    var img = document.getElementById('element');
    this.i--;
    if (this.i < 0) {
      this.i = imgs.length - 1;
    }
    img.src = imgs[this.i].src;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>photos</title>
  <script src="photos.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <input type='button' value='<' name='next' onclick="arr.next('mainImg')" />
  <img id='mainImg' src="cake.png">
  <input type='button' value='>' name='prev' onclick="arr.prev('mainImg')" />


</body>

</html>
```

Not using jquery. I do not have enough experience in js either. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had three mistakes:

1. You referenced the images as `img.src = imgs[this.i].src;` and you just had an array of strings, not an array of objects with a `src` property. `img.src = imgs[this.i];` is the correct way to get the URL.
2. You used

   ```
   var img = document.getElementById('element');
   ```

   when you should have used

   ```
   var img = document.getElementById(element);
   ```

   `element` is an argument coming from your `onclick` event. It holds the `id` of your image that you should be using. `"element"` is just a string. You try to find an element with `id` equal to `element` which doesn't exist.
3. **Edit:** You should also use `&lt;` and `&gt;` to represent `<` and `>`. Otherwise your HTML might get screwed up. More on that [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp).

```js
var arr = new collection(['http://images.math.cnrs.fr/IMG/png/section8-image.png', 'https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Test/xhtml-print/20050519/tests/jpeg444.jpg', "http://saturnraw.jpl.nasa.gov/multimedia/images/raw/casJPGFullS72/N00183828.jpg"]);

function collection(imgs) {
  this.imgs = imgs;
  this.i = 0;

  this.next = function(element) {
    var img = document.getElementById(element);
    
    this.i++;
    if (this.i >= imgs.length) {
      this.i = 0;
    }

    img.src = imgs[this.i];
  };
 
  this.prev = function(element) {
    var img = document.getElementById(element);
  
    this.i--;
    if (this.i < 0) {
      this.i = imgs.length - 1;
    }
  
    img.src = imgs[this.i];
  };
  
  this.next("mainImg"); // to initialize with some image
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>photos</title>
  <script src="photos.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <input type='button' value='<' name='next' onclick="arr.next('mainImg')" />
  <img id='mainImg' src="cake.png">
  <input type='button' value='>' name='prev' onclick="arr.prev('mainImg')" />


</body>

</html>
```

This is how I'd personally do it:

```js
var myCollection = new Collection([
  "http://images.math.cnrs.fr/IMG/png/section8-image.png",
  "https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Test/xhtml-print/20050519/tests/jpeg444.jpg",
  "http://saturnraw.jpl.nasa.gov/multimedia/images/raw/casJPGFullS72/N00183828.jpg"
], "mainImg");

document.getElementById("next_btn").onclick = function() {
  myCollection.next();
};

document.getElementById("prev_btn").onclick = function() {
  myCollection.prev();
}

function Collection(urls, imgID) {
  var imgElem = document.getElementById(imgID);
  var index = 0;

  this.selectImage = function() {
    imgElem.src = urls[index];
  };

  this.next = function() {
    if (++index >= urls.length) {
      index = 0;
    }

    this.selectImage();
  };

  this.prev = function(element) {
    if (--index < 0) {
      index = urls.length - 1;
    }

    this.selectImage();
  };

  // initialize
  this.selectImage();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>photos</title>
  <script src="photos.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="next_btn" type='button' value='&lt;' />
  <img id='mainImg'>
  <input id="prev_btn" type='button' value='&gt;' />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @SevinjJafarli You can check my edit snippet that I added to see how I would personally do it.

Answer (score 0):

Why sending string into arr.next('mainImg') function ?
your img element always have the same id, only change src. 
and document.getElementById(element) is also the same img element.

html: `<img id='mainImg' src="cake.png">`

js: `document.getElementById('mainImg')`

consider img element as a container, and id is it's identifiler.

Answer (score 0):

```
var start_pos = 0;

var img_count = document.getElementsByClassName('icons').length - 1;

var changeImg = function(direction){

pos = start_pos = (direction == "next")? (start_pos == img_count)? 0 : start_pos+1 : (start_pos == 0)? img_count : start_pos-1;

console.log(pos)

}


document.getElementById('left').onclick = function(){ changeImg("previous"); }
document.getElementById('right').onclick = function(){ changeImg("next"); }
```

Comment: Sorry about the no explanation.  This can be done in one line and all these over done responses need this example.